# Is full size website non responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have some concept of my website and don't really wanna change it very much.

Nowadays, everyone has to think about mobile users, however most of the websites are running smoothly on any smartphone.

What if I just make my website have permanent size like width: 1200px, height: 100%. It makes the website look the same on any device.

Will this bring any side effects or unwanted behavior?

Why would I think about page elements to move responsively, while the website can look the same on a PC, tablet or smartphone.

Please help me understand.

Comment: You can make something a fixed width (like 1000px), but not all screens show the same number of pixels so it will look different on different screens. If your site was 1000px wide I could see the whole thing on my computer, but only a portion on my old phone - I would have to scroll horizontally.

Comment: But the page will have the same elements order, everything is on its place like I designed it. No drastic changes required then

Comment: If you want to force mobile users to have to scroll horizontally and zoom manually then sure, go for it.

Comment: I think that people will not be confused then. No more searching for buttons that they know from PC version and disapear on mobiles. Isnt it comfortable?

Comment: I don't think so. I like having a special navigation bar better suited to mobile. I like that unnecessary elements are removed on mobile since I have a smaller screen. I like that text is larger for my smaller screen. I hate using full websites on mobile. You can see that no professional companies do this, so you can see which opinion is the majority.

Answer (score 2):

```
Generally speaking you want the entire site to be viewed without side scrolling. Many mobile devices don't have a 1200px width, which means they would have to side scroll on your page. If you're aiming to have side scrolling and there isn't a large amount of vertical content it might just be a different experience than most users expect.
```

(See above paragraph for example)
    You might also make sure your page has horizontal scroll bars on small screens because they don't default on all devices. When mobile users view your page with their device on it's side you might also find that if you have more than 4 small buttons vertically aligned that they also get a vertical scroll bar.
    The worst thing is probably that they're bound to never see all of your content at any given time. Now that's not a big deal if it's a small content in sections that are clearly defined so they can view each section. However if you have large banner images or text going across the whole page then they will have to scroll to see the whole image, or back and forth for each line of text. The more users have to work to see your content the less interested they are in seeing it.
    Over 50% of google searches are done on mobile, that's likely your market and you should consider what could happen if you accidentally alienate mobile users with your site.